# What does this do?

Tags: php

I've never seen `$ret = N.T.T.T.T.'<div id="toptabs">';` or anything like it, it seems like this would throw a parse error... can anyone explain why it doesn't?

```
public function renderTabs() {
    if(empty($this->currentTabs)) {
        return '';
    }

    $ret = N.T.T.T.T.'<div id="toptabs">';
    if(!empty($this->currentTabs['left'])) {
        $ret .= $this->doTabs($this->currentTabs['left'], 'left');
    }
    if(!empty($this->currentTabs['right'])) {
        $ret .= $this->doTabs($this->currentTabs['right'], 'right');
    }
    $ret .= N.T.T.T.T.'</div>';

    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: So...many...identical...answers...

Comment: Everyone's writing at the same time. My screen popped up with "10 new answers" as I was writing mine.

Comment: After reading the answers, I think `N` and `T` may be [constants](http://php.net/constants). :-)

Comment: All great minds think alike ;)

Answer (score 3):

`N` and `T` seems like [constants](http://php.net/constants)
and `.` concatenating it

from the naming and usage I can assume that `N` represents a newline character and `T` a tab.

You have never seen it as it's quite odd way to write such things

```
$ret = "\n\t\t\t\t<div id='toptabs'>";
```

or just

```
$ret = "
                <div id='toptabs'>";
```

looks more familiar

Anyway, all this formatting shouldn't be used at all, as all output should be handled by template letting to write such formatting as is

Answer (score 3):

I would assume these are constants defined somewhere to indicate New Lines and Tabs.

```
define("T", "\t");
define("N", "\r\n");
```

Answer (score 2):

Pretty you have two [**`define`**](http://fr.php.net/define)s somewhere, like those :

```
define('T', "\t");
define('N', "\n");
```

So `T` would be a tabulation, and `N` a newline.

Answer (score 2):

To the parser, `N` and `T` are constants, presumably strings (but at any rate, they are presumed to be variables of a type that can be concatenated into strings). Like any other strings, they may be concatenated together.

Answer (score 2):

I'm willing to bet that `N` is a constant with a new line (probably 
) and `T` is a tab (probably 4 spaces; 4x  `&nbsp;`)

Also, remember that `.` is a concatenation operator in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether these are constants by using [`defined()`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php)

Answer (score 1):

`N` and `T` should be [constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php)

Answer (score 1):

`N` and `T` are probably meant to be constants of that name.

PHP's sloppy treatment of constants will however resolve them to literal "N" and "T" if they're not defined. (You would get a `E_NOTICE` level warning about that though.)

Try `echo constant("N");` to see whether they exist.

Answer (score 1):

`N` and `T` and constants being concatenated together.

PHP documentation on constants:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php

Answer (score 1):

N and T are probably global constants defined to be something like new line and tab.  Its not very nice though IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Those look like constants defined as N and T somewhere else in the script. Look for something like:

define("N", $somevalue);
define("T", $somevalue);

It looks like the script is appending them together.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define constants N and T somewhere before this code.